# Does the Edge browser support HTML5 Server Side Events?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, server-sent-events

Does Microsoft Edge support the [HTML5 SSE (Server Side Events)](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)?

Comment: As of Sept 11, 2015, SSE appears to be still "under consideration".  I suspect that the best way to get Microsoft to actually implement it is to increase the number of web sites out there that use it --and say, "sorry, your browser is so inferior it doesn't support SSE, so this web site cannot be properly enjoyed by you until you switch to a browser that does support it, like Firefox and Chrome and Opera and Safari and ..."  :)

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim Couldn't aggree more... Still "Under Consideration"...

Comment: Still under consideration in July 2017... Just tell your users to switch to a more "mainstream" browser, Edge will never be mainstream as long as Microsoft lets their internal politics dominate.

Comment: It has been 'Under Review' since 06.08.2015, as a result I have a feeling that this won't be implemented based on how slow the progress has been thus far, quite disappointed.

Comment: There are few polyfills available. https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js and https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource

Answer (score 16):

At the time of this response, we (the Microsoft Edge team) are currently giving serious consideration to Server-Sent Events. You can track further developments on [our *Status* site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/serversenteventseventsource/?q=sort%3AVotes), and express your support for this feature by voting for it on [uservoice.modern.ie](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263825-server-sent-events-eventsource).

Comment: It is now at the highest vote , are you guys started working on it already? Our chatroom needs it.

Comment: Still "Under Consideration" while all other browsers support them. It's been two years now... As much as I like Microsoft, how can I defend Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge against my fellow worker? We need SSE for our web app. How does Microsoft expect people to like their browser and their softwares?

Comment: @Sampson The link to your "*Status* site" is broken.

Comment: @iokanuon - the link has now been updated. But the status hasn't improved!

Comment: I guess the switch of Edge to the Blink engine would solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Update: SSE is now supported in Chromium Edge, the next iteration of HTML Edge

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/serversenteventseventsource/?q=sort%3AVotes

Answer (score 4):

No, Microsoft Edge doesn't support SSE.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-project-spartan-platform/suggestions/6263825-server-sent-events-eventsource

Answer (score 0):

Could check the status of SSE supporting for various browsers in here: https://caniuse.com/eventsource, although the listed release version might not be exhaustive.